# Call Backend Using electron

Tags: javascript, json, electron, electron-packager

So, I am making a small desktop application using electron and P5 (for front-end). I wanna make the application fully working while offline meaning I want to store the data locally instead of using a database. However I cannot change the json files on the frontend meaning I need to somehow call the backend (the main file of the application) from the front-end. Since I am kinda new to electron could anyone tell me how could I make a button call a function on the main file? I spent a way too much time searching for a solution online but was unable to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable nodeIntegration, then you can use the built-in node process via electron remote module.

So, in your main.js **enable the nodeIntegration:**

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        // ...
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        }
        // ...
    });
});
```

Now you can **use electron remote module wherever you want** and make file operations via the fs module:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const fs = remote.require('fs');

fs.writeFile('ourDataStorage.txt', data, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('File has been saved.');
});
```